# Configure the Metasploit SSH client to support `aes256-cbc`

Tags: ssh, metasploit

I am trying to set up a vulnerable machine running `freeSSHd 1.2.6`. The Metasploit exploit module fails with the following error:

```
Server encryption_client preferences: aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,rijndael128-cbc,rijndael192-cbc,rijndael256-cbc,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
Client encryption_client preferences: aes256-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes128-ctr
```

Looking at a similar question and following this [link](https://github.com/rapid7/metasploit-framework/blob/b3c7fff32a62739241a223515574674b4a6b483c/lib/net/ssh/transport/algorithms.rb) I can see that one of the protocols (`aes256-cbc`) offered by the server, should be supported by the Metasploit SSH client. However, it doesn't offer it. Is there any setting I can change in Metasploit to make it offer `aes256-cbc` to the vulnerable SSH server?

Answer (score 1):

Find file that you mentioned:

```
$ find /usr/share/metasploit-framework -type f -name algorithms.rb    
/usr/share/metasploit-framework/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/net-ssh-6.1.0/lib/net/ssh/transport/algorithms.rb
```

Edit it and add cipher that you need, in `DEFAULT_ALGORITHMS/encryption` section:

```
DEFAULT_ALGORITHMS = {
  host_key: %w[ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com
               ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com
               ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com
               ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
               ecdsa-sha2-nistp384
               ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
               ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com
               ssh-rsa-cert-v00@openssh.com
               ssh-rsa],

  kex: %w[ecdh-sha2-nistp521
          ecdh-sha2-nistp384
          ecdh-sha2-nistp256
          diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256
          diffie-hellman-group14-sha1],



encryption: %w[aes256-ctr aes192-ctr aes128-ctr **aes256-cbc**],
```

Rerun msfconsole and now it should work.